# Не работает запрос PDO из нескольких частей

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Есть скрипт который отправляет запрос в БД и при определенном условии добавляет данные. Сам запрос через phpmyadmin отрабатывает правильно. А вот при запуске через php в cron ничего не происходит. В cpanel запускаю так: /usr/local/bin/php /home/логин/public_html/скрипт.php На почту оповещение тоже не приходит. В логах появляется ошибка: `PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function query() on null in /home/логин/public_html/скрипт.php:14` Подскажите, пожалуйста, что я делаю не так?

```
<?php
     $host = 'localhost';
    $db   = 'xxxxx';
    $user = 'xxxxx';
    $pass = 'xxxxx';
    $charset = 'utf8';

    $dsn = "mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db;charset=$charset";
    $opt = [
        PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
        PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
        PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES   => false,
    ];

$stmt = $pdo->query('CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE `tmp_table`
SELECT 
rl.`p_af_id`, 
    (FLOOR(COUNT(*) / 2) * 1000) AS `amount`,   
    CONCAT(Бонус за пару:, ' ', GROUP_CONCAT(rl.`af_id` , ',')) AS 

`description`, 
    `bonus` AS `source`, 
    COUNT(*) as `Ref_count`
FROM `xxxxx_u_m_relat` rl     
GROUP BY `p_af_id`
HAVING COUNT(*) MOD 2 = 0;

INSERT INTO `xxxxx_u_ref`(`af_id`, `amount`, `status`,`visit_id`, 
`description`, `source`, `reference`, `reference_details`, `p_ref_id`, 
`c_ref_id`, `Ref_count`)  
SELECT 
t.`p_af_id`, 
    t.`amount`,   
    2 AS `status`, 
    0 AS `visit_id`, 
    t.`description`, 
    `bonus` AS `source`, 
    0 AS `reference`, 
    `Bonus` AS `reference_details`, 
    0 AS `p_ref_id`, 
    0 AS `c_ref_id`, 
    t.`Ref_count`
FROM `tmp_table` t
LEFT JOIN `xxxxx_u_ref` rf ON t.`p_af_id` = rf.`af_id` AND t.`source` = rf.`source`
WHERE rf.`af_id` IS NULL;  

UPDATE `xxxxx_u_ref` rf
INNER JOIN `tmp_table` t ON t.`p_af_id` = rf.`af_id`
    AND t.`source` = rf.`source`
SET
rf.`amount` = t.`amount`,
    rf.`description` = t.`description`,
    rf.`Ref_count` = t.`Ref_count`
WHERE rf.`Ref_count` > 0 AND t.`Ref_count` > rf.`Ref_count`');

?>
```

UPD Спасибо. С переменной совсем затупила. Немного исправила. Добавила: `$pdo = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass, $opt);` Но теперь ошибка другая:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 5 in /home/логин/public_html/скрипт.php:19
Stack trace:
#0 /home/логин/public_html/скрипт.php(19): PDO->query('CREATE TEMPORAR...', ')) AS \n\n`descri...')
#1 {main}
  thrown in /home/логин/public_html/скрипт.php on line 19
```

UPD 2
После разделения кода:

```html
<?php
  $host = 'localhost';
    $db   = 'xxxxx';
    $user = 'xxxxx';
    $pass = 'xxxxx';
    $charset = 'utf8';

    $dsn = "mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db;charset=$charset";
    $opt = [
        PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
        PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
        PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES   => false,
    ];
$pdo = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass, $opt);
$stmt = $pdo->query("CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE `tmp_table`
SELECT 
rl.`p_af_id`, 
    (FLOOR(COUNT(*) / 2) * 1000) AS `amount`,   
    CONCAT('Бонус за пару:', ' ', GROUP_CONCAT(rl.`af_id` , ',')) AS 

`description`, 
    'bonus' AS `source`, 
    COUNT(*) as `Ref_count`
FROM `xxxxx_u_m_relations` rl     
GROUP BY `parent_affiliate_id`
HAVING COUNT(*) MOD 2 = 0;");

$stmt = $pdo->query("INSERT INTO `xxxxx_uap_referrals`(`af_id`, `amount`, `status`,`visit_id`, 
`description`, `source`, `reference`, `reference_details`, `p_ref_id`, 
`c_ref_id`, `Ref_count`)  
SELECT 
t.`p_af_id`, 
    t.`amount`,   
    2 AS `status`, 
    0 AS `visit_id`, 
    t.`description`, 
    'bonus' AS `source`, 
    0 AS `reference`, 
    'Bonus' AS `reference_details`, 
    0 AS `p_ref_id`, 
    0 AS `c_ref_id`, 
    t.`Ref_count`
FROM `tmp_table` t
LEFT JOIN `xxxxx_u_ref` rf ON t.`p_af_id` = rf.`af_id` AND t.`source` = rf.`source`
WHERE rf.`af_id` IS NULL; "); 

$stmt = $pdo->query("UPDATE `xxxxx_u_ref` rf
INNER JOIN `tmp_table` t ON t.`p_af_id` = rf.`af_id`
    AND t.`source` = rf.`source`
SET
rf.`amount` = t.`amount`,
    rf.`description` = t.`description`,
    rf.`Ref_count` = t.`Ref_count`
WHERE rf.`Ref_count` > 0 AND t.`Ref_count` > rf.`Ref_count`");

?>
```

Comment: Редактура вопроса лишает его смысла. В текущем виде этот код не может выдать процитированную  ошибку

Comment: про вторую ошибку написано в ответе после слов "во-вторых"

Comment: А Вы не подскажете что нужно переписать чтобы исправить этот скрипт? Я совсем не понимаю.

Comment: Я не знаю, как это другими словами написать. Вы понимаете, что CREATE TABLE  - это один запрос, INSERT - другой, а UPDATE - третий? Вы сами эти запросы писали или просто скопировали весь кусок откуда-то и не вчитывались в него?

Comment: Я понимаю что это три куска запроса. Я не понимаю как в PDO это записать правильно. Ну или как правильно составить этот запрос для выполнения в cron.

Comment: Это не три куска запроса. Это **три разных запроса**. Каждый должен быть выполнен отдельно, через свой отдельный вызов $pdo->query. **Крон здесь абсолютно не при чем.** Если знаете как выполнить без крона - то пишите

Comment: Поняла, спасибо. Добавила код сверху. Ошибок не выдаёт. Как думаете так лучше?

Comment: Если не выдает, значит, скорее всего, работает

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Он не только в кроне не будет работать, а вообще где угодно.  Весь скрипт - одна сплошная опечатка.

Во-первых, как там и говорит сообщение об ошибке, **если его прочитать**, переменная $pdo нигде не определена. При копи-пастинге кода последняя строчка потерялась.

Во-вторых, pdo::query() выполняет **один запрос за раз**, то есть надо написать $pdo->query столько раз, сколько запросов надо выполнить.

Это то что на поверхности, могут быть и другие проблемы. По остальным читать сообщения об ошибках, если будут